# when getting items from spinner the application crashes - android

Tags: android, spinner

I have an `Activity` with a `Button` and when I click the `Button` I get a custom dialog with a `Spinner` and 3 `EditText`s  and a OK button.
when I click the Ok button I want to get the Data from the 3 EditText and from the spinner . But when trying to get the data from the spinner the application crashes

the code:

```
    dialogButtonOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                spinnerEvents = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerForEvents);
                    String MakeYears = Years.getText() + " Years";
                    String MakeMonths = Months.getText() + " Months";
                    String MakeDays = Days.getText() + " Days";
                    String MakeDate = MakeYears + " " + MakeMonths + " " + MakeDays;

                    String MakeEventName = spinnerEvents.getSelectedItem().toString();

                 dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

hope someone can help
thanks !!

the Exception is:

```
07-21 17:15:08.377  19898-19898/as.ga.myapp_v1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at as.ga.myapp_v1.Activity2$1$1.onClick(Activity2.java:167)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i wrote the exception

Comment: line 167 is : String MakeEventName = spinnerEvents.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: Check that `spinnerForEvents` exists in the layout you've inflated

Comment: he is . <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerForEvents"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:entries="@array/Events_Array"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of findViewById(R.id.spinnerForEvents),try calling (Your dialog view layout root view).findViewById(R.id.spinnerForEvents).

Check your `getSelecetdItem()` is not null before calling `toString()` method.

```
if(spinnerEvents != null && spinnerEvents.getSelectedItem() !=null ) {
   makeEventName = (String)spinnerEvents ();
} else  { 

}
```

Or try this. Remove the logic of getting spinner value inside `dialogButtonOK.setOnClickListener`

```
String makeEventName="";

spinnerEvents.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {             
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,int position, long id) {
                // On selecting a spinner item
                makeEventName= adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
});
```

Comment: it is null . why is it null ?! i have the line spinnerEvents = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerForEvents);

Comment: INSIDE strings.XML         <string-array name="Events_Array">
        <item>Event One</item>
        <item>Event Two</item>
        <item>Event Three</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: somthing is messed up because i inserted the setOnItemSelectedListener and when i choose item it doesnt get into this funtion of onitemselected

Comment: Is your spinnerEvents null or spinnerEvents.getSelecetdItem() null?

Comment: spinnerEvents is null for some reason .

Comment: try cleaning and rebuildin your project once

Comment: Instead of findViewById(R.id.spinnerForEvents),try calling (Your dialog view layout root view).findViewById(R.id.spinnerForEvents)

Comment: i did what you said. the spinnerEvents is still null

Comment: findViewById() search for views within your Activity's layout and not your dialog's view

Comment: ummm.. whats are my options ? and by the way . the three editText is reachable and i can get the data from them.

Comment: Those EditText fields, you might have initialized while inflating the dialog view.When you are inflating the dialog view, you get the rootview.Use that rootview.findViewById().

Comment: sure where ?? its very long

Comment: upload in dropbox or google drive ,make it public and give me the url

Comment: WOW ! my bad you got it ! spinnerEvents = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinnerForEvents);   i forgot the dialog.* so this is why it wasnt found ! thanks alot Renjith.